# How to keep calling java instance jobject for new threads created by C++ in JNI

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, java-native-interface

As you know, in JNI native method implementation, the function takes in caller instance jobject as argument. However, If I save this jobject globally, and try to use `env->CallVoidMethod` with this jobject instance in a separate thread, the returned method is always NULL. I suspect C++ threads cannot use this caller jobject instance just as they cannot use `JNIenv` instance if they do not attach. Is there a work around for this problem? Here is the code :

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject this_object, jshort server_port)
{
    this_instance = new jobject();
    *this_instance = thisObject;
    Test test();
}

class Test
{
    Test()
    {
        new boost::thread([]() {
             JNIEnv *env_ = get_env();
             jclass try_class = env_->GetObjectClass(*this_instance);

             jmethodID  on_subscription_request_id_try =
                env_->GetMethodID(try_class, "onSubscriptionRequest", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z");

             char *k = new char[2];
             k[0] = 'a';
             k[1] = '\0';
             jstring trip_id = env->NewStringUTF(k);
             jstring token = env->NewStringUTF(k);
              bool can_subscribe = env_->CallBooleanMethod(*this_instance, on_subscription_request_id, k, k);

        })
    }
}
```

I have tried to run the code in the constructor of class test directly in the function Java_test with `this_object` directly, and everything works fine. But when I run it in a separate thread, I get a segmentation fault
when `env_->CallBooleanMethod` is fired. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Note : get_env is a method I have written that attaches a thread and returns and environment. It works for all the other cases, like using `NewStringUTF`. Here is the code :

```
JNIEnv * get_env()
{
    JNIEnv *env;
    jint result = jvm->GetEnv((void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_8);
    if (result != JNI_OK)
    {
        jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void **)&env, NULL);
    }
    return env;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Turns out there is a method in JNIenv called `NewGlobalRef` which takes in a jobject to return a global reference. If this is not done, every input to implemented native methods, like jstring, jobject will be destroyed. You can not simply just pass it into a thread, as the memory is lost upon the end of the native method.

Comment: Thx alot!  For those who land here ' env->DeleteGlobalRef()' is what you need to delete the global ref.